# Ember js pre2: default action for 'selector'

Tags: ember.js

As an example we have a log in view with 'username', 'password' and 'country' fields and a 'login'.

How can one invoke the action related to the 'login' button when pressing enter on any of the inputs in a group.?  For instance, all inputs within a container of some sort (div, form, fieldset, etc).

Comment: is the action related to the login view a standard form `submit` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your form controls trigger the `sumbit` action you could define your controls of type `submit`.

```
...
{{input type="submit" ...}}
...
<button type="submit">...</button>
...
```

or the more elegant way is to having your parent view catch all the events and trigger the `submit` once, but this depends how nested your view is.

Hope it helps

Comment: Ah, so I can check the `keypressed` event in the parent view and `send` or invoke the controller action once I detect enter being pressed?

Comment: I accepted this since it appears to be slightly more flexible but @Anonymous' answer is also an option in some cases.

Comment: @EbenRoux, yes you can let the event bubble up and catch it at a higher hierarchy level and invoke your controller action, but make sure none of your childviews stop's the event propagation before it get's to the parentview.

Answer (score 1):

Put your action on your form tag, like so:

```
<form {{action yourAction on="submit"}}>
{{input text}}
{{input text}}
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

This will cause your event to fire whenever the form is submit (by clicking the button, by hitting enter in a field, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to have the same thing happen in a `<div>`?  I guess being restricted to a `form` is not the worst thing in the world but it would be nice to be able to group on any container.  I'll give this a try as soon as I can.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for all controls but +1 since it *does* work :)